# Is there a formula that will count how many times "@" is used in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a column of cells that each cell contains multiple emails.  I want to create a formula that will give me a total of all emails in each cell.

Cell `A1` Contains ("email@msn.com,email@gmail.com,email@fun.com")

I'd like help in figuring out how to count the number of emails in `A1` which would be "3".  Can this be done by counting the `@` sign?

I have a very large spreadsheet with thousands of emails that I need to total.

I have tried `CountA`, `Count`, `Search` but can't figure this out.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
=LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "@", ""))
```

This compares the length of the original cell to the length with all `@` synbols removed, to infer the number of `@` symbols.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for.